# Not able to display current location

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am building an app that displays the current location using the Geo Locator package available in the flutter packages .I am using the latest version 7.6.1.There is button called 'Get Location' .On clicking that it must print the location .

As soon as i click the get Location button I get this error
[Error_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BMUO.png)

This is My Pubspec.yaml file

```
name: clima
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  geolocator: ^7.6.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - images/city_background.jpg
    - images/location_background.jpg

  fonts:
  - family: Spartan MB
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/SpartanMB-Black.otf
      weight: 900
```

AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clima">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:label="clima"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My info.plist file for the ios

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>clima</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is my code

Main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/screens/loading_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: LoadingScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Under the Screens Directory I have
3 files

city_screen.dart,loading_screen.dart,location_screen.dart

city_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants1.dart';

class CityScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CityScreenState createState() => _CityScreenState();
}

class _CityScreenState extends State<CityScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/city_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: null,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'Get Weather',
                  style: kButtonTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

loading_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

      Future<void> getLocation()
      async {
        LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low); //high is battery consuming
        print(position);
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                getLocation();//Get the current location
              },
              child: Text('Get Location'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Location_screen.dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants1.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
  @override
  Future<void> getLocation()
  async {
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/location_background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8), BlendMode.dstATop),
          ),
        ),
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.location_city,
                      size: 50.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      '32°',
                      style: kTempTextStyle,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '☀️',
                      style: kConditionTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  "It's  time in San Francisco!",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                  style: kMessageTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Under utilites directory there is one file
constants1.dart

constants1.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const kTempTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 100.0,
);

const kMessageTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
  fontSize: 60.0,
);

const kButtonTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 30.0,
  fontFamily: 'Spartan MB',
);

const kConditionTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontSize: 100.0,
);
```

Under the services directory i have weather.dart

weather.dart

```
class WeatherModel {
  String getWeatherIcon(int condition) {
    if (condition < 300) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 400) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition < 600) {
      return '☔️';
    } else if (condition < 700) {
      return '☃️';
    } else if (condition < 800) {
      return '';
    } else if (condition == 800) {
      return '☀️';
    } else if (condition <= 804) {
      return '☁️';
    } else {
      return '‍';
    }
  }

  String getMessage(int temp) {
    if (temp > 25) {
      return 'It\'s  time';
    } else if (temp > 20) {
      return 'Time for shorts and ';
    } else if (temp < 10) {
      return 'You\'ll need  and ';
    } else {
      return 'Bring a  just in case';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your getLocation method you are not checking for permissions... you ask user permission but then you do not check them.

First check permission and see what it is and if its granted then do the rest of the logic.

If the problem isn't here post the next log so we can figure out what the problem is

Comment: Thanks mate it worked :) .